# Using JQuery to change an image

Tags: php, jquery, image, toggle

I have a table where every other row is hidden.  When I click an image, it will display the hidden row and hide all other rows.  I'm able to show and hide the rows ok, but for some reason the image will not roll over.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleByID(id) {
     $('.data-row-hidden').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == "row"+id) {
               $(this).toggle(500);
               $('#img'+id).attr("src", "images/toggle_expand.png");
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide();
               $('#img'+id).attr("src", "images/toggle_collapse.png");
          }
     });
}
</script>
```

Here is the code I'm using for the hidden row:

```
<tr id="<?='row'.$value['property_id']?>" class="data-row-hidden">
```

Here is the code I'm using to call the function:

```
<img id="<?='img'.$value['property_id']?>" src="images/toggle_collapse.png" border="0" height="20" width="20" onclick="javascript:toggleByID(<?=$value['property_id']?>)">
```

Comment: What do you mean it will not roll over? Also, could you post the markup?

Comment: I updated the code to show the markup.  i use PHP to generate unique row and image id's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleByID(id) {
     $('.data-row-hidden').each(function(index) {
          var newImage = new Image();
          if ($(this).attr("id") == "row"+id) {
               $(this).toggle(500);
               newImage.src = "images/toggle_expand.png";
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide();
               newImage.src = "images/toggle_collapse.png";
          }
          //cache busting 
          newImage.src = newImage.src + "&_=" + new Date().getTime();
          $('#img'+id).attr("src", newImage.src);
     });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your else condition to

```
    else {
           $(this).hide();
           $('#img'+id).show();
           $('#img'+id).attr("src", "images/toggle_collapse.png");
      }
```